# What is a fast structure to organise collections in MongoDB to store trade data?

Tags: database, mongodb, pymongo, algorithmic-trading, cryptocurrency

I am storing historical trade data from several crypto exchanges. Each exchange lists different symbols, such as `"BTC-28MAR19_FUTURES", "BTC-31MAR19_FUTURES"`, etc. which can be traded, totalling to up to 500 different symbols. For each of these symbols exists trade data, which is something like `"timestamp", "price", "volume"`, etc. There are multiple millions of trades per symbol, which I need to store.

I used to create one collection per exchange and store each symbol of these exchanges into this single collection, i.e.:

collection `name = bitmex_futures`, which contains all trades for all existing products on this exchange. Entries look like this:

```
{"symbol" : "BTC-28MAR19", "price" : 4500, "trade_id" : 12345, etc.}
{"symbol" : "BTC-28MAR19", "price" : 4300, "trade_id" : 12346, etc.}
{"symbol" : "BTC-31MAR19", "price" : 4230, "trade_id" : 12347, etc.}
```

However, this is very slow since there are so many entries, if I want to query the data.

Would it make sense to create a single collection for each symbol? If I end up having 500 collections with up to millions of trade data in each of these, would this still be fast (or even faster)?

Comment: You can have a look at https://github.com/manahl/arctic/ (I may work for manahl...)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to query across trade symbols one collection per trade symbol might make sense. If your `trade_id` is unique I would supply that as the `_id` so you get to use the automatic unique index that is created for `_id`.

What are the query patterns? It may suit to create a [compound index](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-compound/) on the fields you want to query on together.

In general, you should be adding indexes to the fields that you query. You can use an `explain()` [plan](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.explain/) to ensure that your queries are being executed efficiently.

If you are new to MongoDB [this free online class](https://university.mongodb.com/courses/M001/about) is a good place to start.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comments. ```trade_id``` per symbol are unique. I generally query 1-10 symbols and need all trades in a specific time range for those.

I read that creating an index makes sense, but rarely touched these features from MongoDB so far.

Comment: Added a link to a free online class for beginners. You can level up from there. All of our online training is free.

Comment: From experience, the Free MongoDB University courses are really really good. I highly recommend you take a look as per @JoeDrumgoole has mentioned.

Comment: @JoeDrumgoole Why does it only make sense if I do not need to query across trade symbols? E.g. sometimes I query three different trade symbols and use their data.

Would it potentially make sense to use one collection per symbol, but if I resample the timestamp afterwards to a unified format (i.e. aggregate every hour) then for the resulting new set of time series I would only use a single collection.

Comment: If you want to query across trade symbols then put them all in one collection and index by trade symbol.